# 2003 Honda Civic Si Hatchback

Tags: honda, struts, trunk

What part should I replace on 3rd door (hatch) ? 
It will not stay up. Maybe the struts? When i search for the part I can only find struts for the body suspension.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the gas struts have failed or at least got weak.

These may be the ones you want : https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/2-x-Honda-Civic-MK7-2-3-Door-Hatchback-2001-2005-Gas-Tailgate-Boot-Struts-E1605/281945714114?hash=item41a5462dc2:g:9esAAOSwImRYI5w-

Comment: yeah just replace the gas strut and dont forget to lubricate hinges